# How an Azure AD Administrator can grant permission to a local app to certain users without giving admin consent?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Let's say I am an Azure AD Administrator who wants to control which users can access a certain application created in my tenant (the application is local).

When I read [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) the following:

> Applications registered in an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant
> are, by default, available to all users of the tenant who authenticate
> successfully.

I'm inclined to believe I don't have to do anything special however that's not the case.

### What I have done?

First thing I have done is disabled ability for the users in my tenant to give consent to 3rd party apps. For this I went to "Enterprise Applications" and then to "User Settings" and turned off consent setting as shown below.

[image]

This I believe is to ensure that users in my tenant can't give access to any random 3rd party application.

Next I created an application in my Azure AD. That application shows up in the list of "Enterprise Applications".

I select the application I just created and go to "Properties" and set "User assignment required" to yes as shown below.

[image]

After this I go into "Overview" and grant explicit permission to a user (Gaurav in this case) as shown below.

[image]

I can also see that two users have been granted access to the application.

[image]

[image]

### Expected Behavior

After all this settings, I am expecting that this user (Gaurav) should be able to sign in into the application.

### Actual Behavior (issue I'm facing)

However when this user tries to connect to this application, it does not work in the sense that the user gets a message that admin consent is required.

[image]

What can I do to avoid the issue I am facing? I am pretty sure there must be some setting that I overlook.

### Please note that:

- The application I created is local to the tenant I am administering.
- It's a native app which by default are multi-tenant however I have changed the app's manifest and made it single tenant.
- As an administrator I don't want to give "admin consent" as it is my understanding that if I do that all users will have access to the application where as I only want certain users to have access to the application. Moreover, as an administrator I don't really want to sign in into that application.

Answer (score 0):

Only users you assign will have access, even if you do admin consent.
Because you have assignments required.

Admin consent means no user will be asked to give consent to the permissions required by the app.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However what I am seeing is that user is not even getting the consent screen. They are seeing this https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqsvx.png instead. My requirement is that once a user is assigned an app, they should be able to access it without an explicit admin consent. Is this possible?

Comment: Your app has permissions required in the Required permissions section that need admin consent, you can't work around that

Comment: No I don't. The permissions this app is asking for are: 1) Sign in and read user profile and 2) Access Azure Service Management API. AFAIK, both of them don't need admin consent.

Comment: Hmm, maybe user consent is disabled in your tenant?

Comment: Interesting! Can you please tell me where can I check that on Azure Portal? I have disabled user consenting but that's for 3rd party apps (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltL1n.png). That should not have an impact on consenting to apps created in the same tenant. Right?

Comment: Ah I missed that image. Yeah that's user consent. It applies to all apps. If you disable it, admins will have to consent to all permissions.

Comment: Thanks! I think we’re getting somewhere :). The tooltip says only about 3rd party apps which is what I want. Why is this setting applied to local apps?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure the tooltip is wrong... It applies to permissions required by service principals.

Comment: I'll double-check with some people of the identity team

Comment: Thanks! I would really appreciate that. Will wait to hear back what AD team has to say.